# jQuery ajax event invoking order

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let say I have a simple function like this.

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(
    function(){alert('global');}
);

$.post('http://www.google.com', 
    { name: "John", time: "2pm" } ,
    function(data,s,xhr) {
        alert('local');
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AT5vt/

It is possible to make the global ajaxSuccess() function getting invoked  before the local success callback? As I want to do a global checking on the result before further processing by the local functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the default ajax post instead of using the custom post handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/AT5vt/1/

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(function() {
     alert('global success');
  }
);

$('body').ajaxError(function() {
     alert('global error');
  }
);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://www.google.com',
  data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" } ,
  complete: function(data,s,xhr) {
    if(xhr.status == 200) {
      alert('local success');
    } else {
      //note you can catch a lot of errors here like 404, 500, 406, 302 etc
      alert("local error");
    }
  }
})
```

didn't put it in jsfiddle as posting to google.com keeps on failing from there but that should work.

Comment: Please note that I am using the success but not complete event. If I changed the global to ajaxComplete, the local runs first, still.

Comment: ermm i thought you wanted ajaxSuccess? why change the global to ajaxComplete?

Comment: note you could still check for a success by checking: if(xhr.status == 200) so you don't actually need your success function

Comment: I want the SAME event to be invoked in an order from global to local.

Comment: like i said, you can still use the same functionality(albeit with another check for success). local precedes global if the event is the same( local success > global success >  local complete > global complete

Comment: According to http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events, I think yours is the only answer. But I want to add that I should have to register global ajaxError() as well since local complete will get invoked regardless of success or fail.

Comment: you CAN add global ajaxError. then in your local complete, put your check there for success and failure instead of defining a separate success/failure function. same thing really. ill update the answer to show you

Comment: In my case xhr.status == 200 does not always means it's a successful invocation. So I need to do some special work.

Comment: yup it's a matter of what you need really. but complete is a more general way of callback for ajax. you can do a bunch of checks there depending on what you need to check(http response, content received, etc)

Answer (score 7):

This is the ajax event invoking order

```
if ( fireGlobals ){
    jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStart");
} 
//Before send event
if ( s.beforeSend && ( s.beforeSend.call( callbackContext, jqXHR, s ) === false || state === 2 ) ) {
    // Abort if not done already and return
    return jqXHR.abort();
}
if ( isSuccess ) {
    // Success Event
    deferred.resolveWith( callbackContext, [ success, statusText, jqXHR ] );
} else {
    // Error Event
    deferred.rejectWith( callbackContext, [ jqXHR, statusText, error ] );
}

if ( fireGlobals ) {
    globalEventContext.trigger( isSuccess ? "ajaxSuccess" : "ajaxError",
        [ jqXHR, s, isSuccess ? success : error ] );
}
//Complete event
completeDeferred.fireWith( callbackContext, [ jqXHR, statusText ] );

if ( fireGlobals ) {
    globalEventContext.trigger( "ajaxComplete", [ jqXHR, s ] );
    // Handle the global AJAX counter
    if ( !( --jQuery.active ) ) {
        jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStop");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet!  I'm assuming this is from the jQuery source?

Comment: It is indeed. Right from the jQuery source.