# jQuery ajax event killing/unbinding

Tags: jquery

This question is related to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481389/jquery-ajax-event-invoking-order/5481433)

Say if I get the below ajax code, is it possible to do some coding in the global success so that the local complete will not be invoked? All I want to do is do some global checking before the result is shown. There are multiple ajax function on the page using different jquery plugin (jqgrid, jqform etc) so wrapping the ajax method should not be an option.

http://jsfiddle.net/AT5vt/1/

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(function(e){
    alert('global');
    $('body').unbind('complete');
} );


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" } ,
    complete: function(data,s,xhr) {
        alert('local');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can simulate an exit function by throwing an exception.

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(function(){
    alert('global');
    throw "golbal error";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AT5vt/9/

This can achieve the result I desired.

Comment: Nice solution. Do you have any functions attached to the window.onerror handler within your pages? throwing an uncaught exception will cause that handler to be fired. Thought it was worth a mention.

Comment: Thanks to pointing this one out for anyone who is interested. For me there's no error handler on the page. Actually I was just trying to stop some undesired stuff to pop out to the output placeholder and force the page to reload (session expire issue if you want to know).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a helper function that runs the Ajax request, and then runs the global code first, followed by the local function which you would pass in.

```
function wrapAjaxCall(type,url,ajaxData,localComplete)
{
    $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: ajaxData,
    complete: function(data,s,xhr) {
        myglobal();
        localComplete();
       }
    })
```

}

That may be not 100% correct by you will get the idea.

Comment: Sorry, not an option for me. Please read my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a boolean Flag to dictate if you should execute the function inside your complete callback.

```
var performLocalComplete = true;

$('body').ajaxSuccess(function(){

    alert('global');

    if(1 == 1) // Your condition to disable the localComplete
    {
         performLocalComplete = false;
    }

});


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" } ,
    complete: function(data,s,xhr) {

        if (performLocalComplete)
        {
            alert('local Complete');
        }
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AT5vt/7/